# calculate approximate time upload files

Tags: java, file-upload

but a problem is a doubt. I'm uploading images from a JAR to my server. I did have a code to calculate how long it took to climb all the server as follows:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
System.out.println("TIME ::: " + (float)(elapsedTime / 1000) + " seg");
```

Now I was thinking about getting an approximate rise time. This JAR up photos of very good quality and the delay time is prolonged, I want to do only as additional information for the user. I could think up the first picture, calculate how much I take for me to upload that picture and that value multiplied by the total value of images that the user has in the selected folder. It seems valid but wanted to come to you if there is somehow a bit more accurate, somehow integrated Java or something very similar.

Right now I upload images to my server this way:

```
public boolean uploadWithThumb(File image, String filename) {
    reconnect();

    try {
        _sftp.cd(Config.Config.IMAGES_FOLDER);
        _sftp.put(new FileInputStream(image), filename, ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE); //no overwrite (, ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE)

        OutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        //preview
        if (Config.Config.WATERMARK_FILE == "" || !(new File(Config.Config.WATERMARK_FILE)).exists()) {
            //no watermark
            Thumbnails.of(image)
                .size(Config.Config.PREVIEW_SIZE, Config.Config.PREVIEW_SIZE)
                .outputQuality(Config.Config.PREVIEW_QUALITY)
                .toOutputStream(output);
        } else {
            BufferedImage prev = Thumbnails.of(image)
                                           .size(Config.Config.PREVIEW_SIZE, Config.Config.PREVIEW_SIZE)
                                           .outputQuality(Config.Config.PREVIEW_QUALITY)
                                           .asBufferedImage();
            int wsize = Config.Config.PREVIEW_SIZE * 75 / 100;
            BufferedImage water = Thumbnails.of(Config.Config.WATERMARK_FILE)
                                            .size(wsize, wsize)
                                            .asBufferedImage();
            Thumbnails.of(prev)
                      .size(Config.Config.PREVIEW_SIZE, Config.Config.PREVIEW_SIZE)
                      .watermark(Positions.CENTER, water, 0.5f)
                      .outputFormat(Utils.getExtensionNoDot(image.getAbsolutePath()))
                      .toOutputStream(output);
        }

        InputStream decodedInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(((ByteArrayOutputStream) output).toByteArray());
        _sftp.cd(Config.Config.PREVIEW_FOLDER);
        _sftp.put(decodedInput, filename, ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE); //no overwrite (, ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE)

        //thumbs
        output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Thumbnails.of(image)
                  .size(Config.Config.THUMBS_SIZE, Config.Config.THUMBS_SIZE)
                  .toOutputStream(output);
        decodedInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(((ByteArrayOutputStream) output).toByteArray());
        _sftp.cd(Config.Config.THUMBS_FOLDER);
        _sftp.put(decodedInput, filename, ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE); //no overwrite (, ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE)
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to obtain the approximate time in upload all the files is to upload one file and compute the speed:

```
long firstImageSize = getImageSize(0); //get the size of the first image in bytes
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
UploadFirstImage();  //Upload the first image
long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
float meanSpeed = (float)firstImageSize/ (float)(elapsedTime / 1000);  //mean speed in bytes/second
```

Once you have obtained the mean upload speed you have to obtain the overall size of all the other images. Then you could calculate the approximate eplapsed time simply dividing:

```
long allImagesSize = 0;
for(int i = 1; i<numImages; i++){
  allImagesSize += getImageSize(i);  //Calculate the size of all the images in bytes
}
System.out.println("Eplapsed time ::: " + (float)(allImagesSize / meanSpeed) + " seg");
```

If you want to update the time estimation in real time you can use a Thread to compute this periodically.

Comment: Hello !, thanks for answering your code but simply a case told me it would take about 226 seconds while it took 50 seconds. I'm getting the file size with file.length ()

Comment: the upload speed is relative to the network usage and the protocols like TCP/IP that vary it's transmission/reception windows. To have a more precise estimation you can recalculate the speed periodically with the same code.